# Cannot display png file in Blazor Wasm - Response should include 'x-content-type-options' header

Tags: blazor-webassembly

Just started building a .net 6 Blazor Wasm app and published a test page to an AWS repository. The page isn't displaying an image.

[image]

[image]

It seems I have to add nosniff to the response headers, but have no idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you please read about [how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541) and apply what you learn to improve your question post? You can also read [ask] for further guidance.

Comment: @starball I'm well aware of how to ask questions. This is a specific error with the browser identifying the issue and the cause. I just don't know how to fix it and am pretty certain somebody has seen and dealt with this before.

Comment: There's no Blazor code in the question, just HTML tags. The `IMG` tag is malformed which can only be done through typos in the source. There are no headers in that HTML snippet

Comment: @Liam this isn't a good question. No code, no HTTP bodies or headers, just images of bad HTML. The *header suggestion* has nothing to do with whether the *server* can return that image or not

Comment: @Liam the very fact you get a suggestion means the server *did* return something, otherwise you'd get a 404. That something was produced by the server, not client-side Blazor. If the response's `Content-Type` is correct and the binary body is an actual PNG, it will be displayed. `x-` headers are custom and always optional. They don't affect how images are displayed

Comment: @Liam in this case though it seems the response was an HTML page. The important warning is the first one, that `Content-Type` is `text/html` instead of `image/png`. The server returned a page instead of an image. Perhaps it's an error page? A login page? A default redirect? Have you tried checking the contents in the browser's `Developer Tools` ? A common problem with SPAs is that they often capture requests meant for the server

Answer (score 0):

Displaying a similar but different graphic in the same folder worked, so I deleted and re-added the image and the problem disappeared.

No idea what actually caused the problem, but I suspect that some internal register that I couldn't see was expecting the file to be text when it was actually an image. Or it could have been AWS S3 screwing things up (though that looked correct from my viewpoint too).